# Chromium/Chrome (V95) headless - EGL implementation not working (--use-gl=egl)

Tags: debian, webgl, chromium, google-chrome-headless, egl

I've been trying for days to run chromium in headless mode with egl but till now no luck, this works fine in my MacOs however not in debian in my case

### Chromium in headfull mode

We can see bellow that despite the other errors/warnings it is able to load egl library => `Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl`

```
# chromium-browser --no-sandbox --use-gl=egl
[3470:3470:0727/182753.680004:ERROR:power_monitor_device_source_stub.cc(11)] Not implemented reached in virtual bool base::PowerMonitorDeviceSource::IsOnBatteryPower()
[3470:3495:0727/182753.874176:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3470:3495:0727/182753.874220:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3470:3495:0727/182753.928709:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3470:3495:0727/182753.928760:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3516:3516:0727/182753.972601:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl, ANGLE is
[3470:3495:0727/182753.978831:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3470:3495:0727/182753.978971:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[3516:3516:0727/182753.988344:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

### Chrimium in headless mode

But when running in headless mode, it cannot load/find the egl library => `Requested GL implementation is not available`

```
# chromium-browser --headless --no-sandbox --use-gl=egl
[0727/183148.622433:ERROR:power_monitor_device_source_stub.cc(11)] Not implemented reached in virtual bool base::PowerMonitorDeviceSource::IsOnBatteryPower()
[0727/183148.622847:INFO:content_main_runner_impl.cc(1100)] Chrome is running in full browser mode.
[0727/183148.628702:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
[0727/183148.640229:ERROR:gl_factory.cc(146)] Requested GL implementation is not available.
[0727/183148.643560:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(161)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0727/183148.657280:ERROR:gl_factory.cc(146)] Requested GL implementation is not available.
[0727/183148.660757:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(161)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0727/183148.683139:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is
[0727/183148.707322:ERROR:process_posix.cc(330)] Unable to terminate process 14586: No such process (3)
[0727/183148.707440:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(600)] BrowserMainRunner::ExitedMainMessageLoop()
[0727/183148.707466:WARNING:internal_linux.cc(66)] Failed to read /proc/14586/stat
[0727/183148.708890:WARNING:discardable_shared_memory_manager.cc(432)] Some MojoDiscardableSharedMemoryManagerImpls are still alive. They will be leaked.
```

And checking on `chrome://gpu` i can assert that OpenGl is disabled and it falls back to use `swiftshader`

[image: Chromium in headless mode with EGL]

Comment: Info: I just tested this with chromium version 103 while running xvfb in the background and it works:

```
export DISPLAY=:11
Xvfb "$DISPLAY" -screen 0 1920x1080x24 &
chromium-browser --no-sandbox --headless --use-gl=egl
```